# sum product dynamic range in excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, sumproduct

I have the following

formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Database!A2:A30)=1)*(YEAR(Database!A2:A30)=2021)*(Database!C2:C30))
```

Problem: In Column A and C are pretty dynamic in the sense that I will be constantly adding new row with data so the range will need to adjust accordingly.

Question: How do I update the formula above to fit my needs?

Answer (score 0):

One choice is to use a structured table and use structured references:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Table1[date])=1)*(YEAR(Table1[date])=2021)*(Table1[Value]))
```

Or you can use INDEX/MATCH

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Database!A2:INDEX(Database!A:A,MATCH(1E+99,Database!A:A)))=1)*(YEAR(Database!A2:INDEX(Database!A:A,MATCH(1E+99,Database!A:A)))=2021)*(Database!C2:INDEX(Database!C:C,MATCH(1E+99,Database!A:A))))
```